# Unicode characters replaced with question marks in the output stream when using a subprocess.run to execute windows command

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I am running the file compare utility [fc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc) with python function `subprocess.run` and want to save the output for later processing. For this I use `subprocess.PIPE` and `subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
from subprocess import run
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

res = run(['fc', src, dst, '/b'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = res.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

(src, dst - paths to compared files, these paths contain cyrillic characters)

The utility works fine, the files are compared, but the text stored in the variable `output` always contains question marks instead of сyrillic characters, for example:

```
Comparing files N:\TEST\?????????.txt and E:\TEST\?????????.TXT
FC: no differences encountered
```

But if I run this command (`fc "N:\Test\Текстовый.txt" "E:\Test\Текстовый.txt" /b`) at command prompt all characters in output are displayed fine.

And if I run the script in a command prompt (`python test.py`) without redirecting the output stream (i.e `run(['fc', src, dst, '/ b'])`), then all the text is also displayed fine in command prompt.

I use python 3.7.7 and Windows 10. The variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` has the value 'utf8'.

What can be done to get normal display of characters in the output stream? Thanks for any help

P.S. Using the shell (`run(f'fc "{src}" "{dst}" /b', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)`) didn't help. As well as adding `chcp 65001` before the command fc (i.e `run(f'chcp 65001 && fc "{src}" "{dst}" /b', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)`).

Comment: fc.exe is a legacy program that's based on ulib.dll. Programs that use ulib write output to the console as Unicode (UTF-16), but when writing to a pipe they use the process OEM codepage (i.e. `CP_OEMCP` or `GetOEMCP()`). If OEM is a legacy encoding such as codepage 437, then it only supports about 250 characters, and all others are best-fit mapped to supported characters (e.g. "α" -> "a") or mapped to "?".

Comment: In Windows 10, you can change the system ANSI and OEM codepages to UTF-8, but that affects all applications and may break some that depend on the legacy system codepages. You can also set the application ANSI/OEM ["activeCodePage"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) to UTF-8, but it requires modifying the manifest in "fc.exe". I checked the latter hack using the manifest tool, mt.exe. Subsequently fc.exe does write UTF-8 to a pipe, which works with Python `subprocess.run(['fc.exe', src, dst, '/b'], capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Eryk. In fact, you helped me even before writing a comment. I found this your post https://bugs.python.org/issue27179#msg267091, it turned out to be very useful for me. For myself, I concluded that it is easier to use python libraries filecmp or difflib for these purposes.